# search the requested file in subfolders and copy to destination

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to copy the listed files in file_list.txt to destination folder from source location, source folder has subfolders. my batch should be capable to search the file in source subfolders and copy to destination folder. same for copy all files with extension .exe. what is wrong with my code. I think, I have missed to search subfolders data. don't know what is the command. please help.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@color 0a
cls

set "dest=D:\destination"
set /p source=Select source path:


for /R %%f in (%source%/*.exe) do copy %%f "%dest%"

echo Copy requested files

for /f %%f in (file_list.txt) do (

    for /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /S /B /A:-D "%source%/%%f"') Do (
                copy "%%F" "%dest%\%USERNAME%"      
    )
)

pause

ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see anything obviously wrong with the code you've posted, although there are possibilities for errors. You have not provided sufficient information, about your current directory, the content of the text file, how the script is invoked or any debugging information.

The following version of your code, requires that you put your file listing text file into the variable definition on line five. I've assumed that the batch file is in the same location as the file listing, and therefore used `%~dp0`. If it is in the current directory instead, then replace that with `%CD%\`, and obviously the fully qualified absolute path if neither.

Next I use some validation to try to ensure that the source, destination, and user input exist. The input location will then become the current directory.

Your provided commands are then run, before the curent directory is returned to its original location.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Color 0A

Set "listdir=%~dp0filelist.txt"
Set "dest=D:\destination"

If Not Exist "%listdir%" GoTo :EOF
If Not Exist "%dest%\" GoTo :EOF

:Ask
ClS
Set "source="
Set /P "source=Select source path: "
If Not Defined source GoTo Ask
PushD "%source:"=%" 2> NUL || GoTo Ask

For /R %%G In (*.exe) Do Copy /Y "%%G" "%dest%"
Echo Copy requested files
For /F "UseBackQ EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ("%listdir%"
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%H In ('Dir "%%~nxG" /S /B /A:-D 2^> NUL'
) Do Copy /Y "%%H" "%dest%\%UserName%"

PopD

Pause
```

Feel free to try the code, and provide some proper debugging information if it still fails to work as intended.